# Do I have to add an extra div in to achieve this?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering, if I wanted the purple colour of the header and the blue colour of the footer to extend 100% across the page, but keep the content in the middle aligned with the orange in the middle, how should I be achieving it?

Do I have to be adding extra 100% divs around the header and footer and colouring in them? It seems like a crap way of doing it.

This is the code I'm working from:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/21/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header" class="thin_width" >

                        <a href="/"><img src="/static/img/header.jpg" id="logo" alt="coming soon" title="coming soon"></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/posts/list/">Link1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/posts/create/">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/about">Link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="thin_width">
            <h1>Sed ut perspiciatis unde</h1>
            <form id="searchForm" action="/search">
                <input type="text" name="kw" class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 b1 ts3" id="field_regular" placeholder="Keyword">
                <input type="text" name="loc" class="field r2 lft dc1 tc5 b1 ts3" id="field_regular" placeholder="Location">
                <input type="submit" class="button r2 b1 ts3" id="button_search" value="Search">
            </form>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>            
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatne voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
       </div>
       <div id="footer" class="thin_width">
           &#169; 2012 Company, Inc.
           <ul>
               <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
               <li><a href="/terms">Terms</a></li>
               <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* GENERAL */
html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:100%; }
p { font size: 13px; margin: 10px 0; padding: 0; }
h1 { font-size: 22px; }  
h2 { font-size: 17px; }  
h3 { font-size: 14px; } 
blockquote { font-style: italic; }

.thin_width { width: 600px; }

#container { min-height: 100%; position: relative; background-color: red;
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {padding-bottom: 80px; background-color: orange;}
#footer { 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    clear: both; 
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#footer li { display:inline; }

#header {background-color: purple;}
```

Comment: You can't combine position:absolute and float:left. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/29/)

How to do it :

Just take out your header and footer from your wrapper `div` and give 100% width to header and footer.

To bring the content of header and footer in center, you need to wrap the contents in your header and footer in a wrapper div, give it a `width` of `600px;` and use `margin: auto;` to bring it in the flow of your page

Comment: Ah this is so close! However, with your example and not much content, the footer doesnt remain docked like it does in the first example: http://jsfiddle.net/HMsKa/30/ Is there a way to easily fix this and keep your clean code?

Comment: @JamesWillson You want your footer to be docked at the bottom even if your page is not long right? you can try this - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thats correct. Ill look into this and see if I can work it out

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I cant work out how to integrate this. Is wrapper on the site you linked to the same as my "container"?

Comment: @JamesWillson doesn't matter what is it, you can modify as per your requirements